# How to create realistic blinking/shining stars in BGE?

Tags: texturing, game-engine, interface, image

How to create realistic blinking/shining stars in BGE? I recently heard that the blender team actually removed the stars option but not sure what or where I can get or see this action. My intent is to create a 3D space thats pure 100% black like space with dot-like-stars. The stars don't have to necessarily be super fancy or anything like Star Trek but you know, some regular old stars. So that whenever I press the P_Key to run my game in BGE i can see the stars surrounding my space ship but the stars should be at a distance in light years. I've tried some HDRI imaging but well... it didn't look so good it looks very pixelated and not high quality view. Another bad thing about using the HDRI imaging is that i have to use texture mode/view to see it which isn't bad but then i loose all visual colors of my space ship and other objects in my virtual space.

Comment: I assume you are comparing to the new Star Trek :) The old one didn't exactly nail the VFX

Comment: do the stars actually need to provide light to anything, or would a simple object with an animation work?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise No, just a simple object with animation would work.

Comment: Wouldn't it work if you use the material view instwad of texture view?

Answer (score -1):

Create an object plane , set the material-setting such glowing-setting as a billboard orientation , find a resource on blenderartist forum or somewhere UVScroll.py script or direct uv anim what is already in the UV section, but the script is better-more Control , create your Gimp or Photoshop . some colorful alpha channel Stars-32x32 or 64x64 enough texture size.
and create a series images how you want to animate the star - should do so
axis y - 2 images
axis x - 2 images
-so that the entire texture will be composed of 4 images , so if you have
a 64x64 image as a texture will be 2 x 64 on each side - that's 128x128 resolution.
UVScroll.blend get somewhere and accordingly do it...
I wish a lot of shining stars
P. S. way I would do it

Comment: Hi, this is a bit unclear and hard to follow. Could to please improve it a bit?

Answer (score -1):

One of my favourite tricks is to use what I call noise layers. So let's find/make a starry image.
Now we simply have to make it flicker! I happen to know that if you get another bit of noise and move it across behind a star-field, so long as the stars are sparse enough, you can't tell. So with a UV scroll script and two UV layers, you can get a reasonable effect

So here you go, here's a blend:
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/40447

Comment: This sounds like a fantastic method! But you didn't give much detail. Could you please add some more?

Comment: answer should be deleted because of lack of information and because the link isn't working anymore